# How to push dynamic object with same speed using UIPushBehavior?

Tags: swift, uidynamicanimator, magnitude, uipushbehavior

I'm not a physics expert.  However, I want to move UILable which has a dynamic height (depends on content) just like **teleprompter**. But when I start behaviour with magnitude 10, it starts moving but suddenly its slow down and I want continuous move up at the same speed.

Below is my code :

```
push = UIPushBehavior(items: [lblText], mode: .instantaneous)
push.setAngle(-.pi/2, magnitude: 10)
animator.addBehavior(push)
```

lblText size is 375*1500

Comment: Make sure that both your friction and resistance are zero https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidynamicitembehavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh is right, try adding friction and resistance.
To add friction, you will have to create UIDynamicItemBehavior

```
let behavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior.init(items: [lblText])
```

Create this with the items that you need to perform your animations on.

Then you can add friction and resistance to it

```
behavior.friction = 0
behavior.resistance = 0
```

And finally add the behavior to the animator

```
animator.addBehavior(behavior)
```

Let me know if this works, happy to help.